# SSRS table report with every other row shaded UNLESS row has an empty cell

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that I've got shading every other row light blue. I'd like to add to the expression so that if the Price_Updated_On field is blank it will shade that row in Gold. I've been unable to work it out and just keep ending up with expected ) errors, no shading at all or another error I can't remember right now.

This produces no shading at all:

```
=SWITCH(IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "WHITE"), IsNothing(Fields!Price_Updated_On.Value), "Gold")
```

This complains [BC30198] ")" expected:

```
=IIF((ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "WHITE"), IIF(Fields!Price_Updated_On.Value="", "Gold"))
```

I can't seem to come up with a version that caused the other error message but, I feel like I'm getting nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't you need a second condition in your second IIF?  ="" ,Gold, (?) White?

Comment: I added it and it still produces an error about ")" missing. The exact error is:

`Failed to preview report.
The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'Textbox15' contains an error: [BC30198] ")" expected.`

Comment: The current non-working version:
`=IIF((ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "WHITE"), IIF(Fields!Price_Updated_On.Value="", "Gold", "White"))`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the expression will need to check for the blank condition first and then use the alternate row color if not blank.

```
=IIF(Fields!Price_Updated_On.Value="", 
    "Gold", 
    IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, 
        "LIGHTBLUE", 
        "WHITE"
        )
    )
```

Comment: That correctly shades the rows gold if the Price_Updated_On field is empty but it's not shading every other row blue and white.

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement - is it not shading at all (white, white, gold, white ) or not counting the Gold rows (white, blue, gold, white)? Or other?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with Hanover's answer unless your requirements are more complex that you state. This will set the colour to Gold if the Price_updated_on field is an empty string. If it isn't empty is simply shades either white or blue depending on if it's and odd or even row number. This might you you get Blue, Gold, Blue White Blue , so it won't "shift" the shading down a row because of the gold row. If that's what you need then I suspect the answer would be more complex.

Comment: The blue and white just isn't taking place. The blue and white is just to make the report easier to read rows so it's not important that they maintain the blue, white, blue cadence if a gold row pops in there.

Comment: You might need to share your report design, show any row and/or column groups too. I've just tested on a simple table and this works exactly as expected.